# Rails 4 and simple_form for associated route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

In my app I have 2 models Foo and Bar. Foo 'has_one' Bar and Bar 'belongs_to' Foo.

My route file looks like this:

```
namespace :baz do
  resources  :foo do
    resources  :bar
  end
end
```

I'm using the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). Thus for a nested route like the one mentioned above, I would expect the following to work:

```
= simple_form_for [:baz , :foo, @bar]  do |f|
```

This line works perfectly fine when creating a new @bar. When I try to edit an existing @bar, it fails however with this error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"baz/bar", :id=>nil, ...
```

I have done some research and it seems like it has something to do with my 'form_for' params. I have tried changing the tag to this:

```
= simple_form_for [:baz , @foo, @bar]  do |f|
```

...and I've made sure to call an instance of @foo in my controller, but then I am presented with an error that the path does not exist.

Could anybody help me see what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1):

With `simple_form_for` you can specific the url of the form using `url` attribute. Try this:

```
= simple_form_for @bar, url: edit_baz_foo_bar_path do |f|
```

I'm not sure if the path I write above is correct, please have look in your routes by run `rake routes`.

Comment: Thanks @LongNguyen. I did try this and it does work, It will however require that I have a separate form for creating or editing my record, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: In this case you can do a check if current action is update or not then change to proper path. I'm currently do that on my project :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly fine:

```
= simple_form_for [:baz , @foo, @bar]  do |f|
```

Probably you are doing something wrong with the assignment in the controller.

If you have something like this in the Baz::FooBarController:

```
class Baz::FooBarController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foo = Foo.find(params['foo_id'])
    @bar = @foo.bars.new
  end

  def edit
    @bar = Bar.find(params['id'])
    @foo = @bar.foo
  end
end
```

Then the new.html.slim with something like this:

```
= simple_form_for [:baz , @foo, @bar]  do |f|
```

Should produce this html:

```
<form id="new_bar" class="simple_form new_bar method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/baz/foo/1/bars" novalidate="novalidate">
```

And equal edit.html.slim:

```
= simple_form_for [:baz , @foo, @bar]  do |f|
```

Should produce this html:

```
<form id="edit_bar_1" class="simple_form edit_bar" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/baz/foo/1/bar/1" novalidate="novalidate">
```

If this does not work for you, or if you decide you want to go with manually setting the path, but you still want to use the form in same partial in both new and edit views, you can do something like this:

```
= simple_form_for @bar, url: @bar.new_record? ? new_baz_foo_bars_url(foo_id: @foo.id) : edit_baz_foo_bar_url(foo_id: @foo.id, id: @bar.id) do
```